# Need help to delete user from multiple servers at once using bash script, "deluser" command not found

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, users

I have multiple servers whose IPs are stored in a text file. All I want to do is access all hosts through ssh and delete the specific user from all hosts simultaneously.

Note: All listed IPs have the same username and password for ssh.

I used:

```
USERID="test"; cat list.txt | while read IP_ADDRESS; do sshpass -p my_password ssh username@$IP_ADDRESS "deluser -f $USERID" ; done
```

Output:

```
bash: deluser: command not found
```

Comment: Loop through all addresses and run `userdel`

Comment: Note the small print in the man page for userdel, especially "This option is dangerous and may leave your system in an inconsistent state." You may also cause unowned files, and files that may later get restored from backups.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at pssh (or parallel-ssh)
It will allow you to do something like this:

parallel-ssh -i HOSTSFILE deluser myuser

This would then loop over all the entries in the hosts file and execute said command.

There are various ways to do the authentication but I would suggest deploying your SSH key first.

See here for more info:
https://www.tecmint.com/execute-commands-on-multiple-linux-servers-using-pssh/

Comment: I did everything but userdel and deluser isn't working.

Comment: I believe the main point is that the command that they try to use on the remote hosts, `deluser`, is not found in the default `PATH` of the user that they connect as.

Comment: Can you add more insight? How to achieve this?

Comment: The post was edited after the facts so I did not have this information. there could be a lot of things wrong but I would start by specifying the exact location to deluser ( /usr/sbin/deluser)

Comment: Surely `deluser` needs to be run as root on the remote machine. And IIRC, running ssh (even as client root) does not bestow sudo privileges on the remote system (for obvious security reasons).